# Using HeaderResponseContainer: No FilteringHeaderResponse is present in the request cycle

Tags: wicket

I'm trying to add a custom `HeaderResponseContainer` in my wicket application. The [tutorial](http://wicketinaction.com/2012/07/wicket-6-resource-management/) looks quite simple (see *Positioning of contributions*), but when I add these lines and run the application I alwas get an `IllegalStateException`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No FilteringHeaderResponse is present in the request cycle.  This may mean that you have not decorated the header response with a FilteringHeaderResponse.  Simply calling the FilteringHeaderResponse constructor sets itself on the request cycle
     at org.apache.wicket.markup.head.filter.FilteringHeaderResponse.get(FilteringHeaderResponse.java:165)
     at org.apache.wicket.markup.head.filter.HeaderResponseContainer.onComponentTagBody(HeaderResponseContainer.java:64)
     at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:71)
     ...
```

Yes, I already saw the note about `FilteringHeaderResponse`. But I am not sure where I should call the constructor. I already tried to add it in `renderHead` before calling `response.render` but I still get the same exception:

```
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        super.renderHead(response);
        FilteringHeaderResponse resp = new FilteringHeaderResponse(response);
        resp.render(new FilteredHeaderItem(..., "myKey"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a decorator that wraps responses in a `FilteringHeaderResponse`:

```
public final class FilteringHeaderResponseDecorator implements IHeaderResponseDecorator {

    @Override
    public IHeaderResponse decorate(IHeaderResponse response) {
        return new FilteringHeaderResponse(response);
    }
}
```

And that set it during application initialization:

```
Override
public void init() {
    super.init();

    setHeaderResponseDecorator(new FilteringHeaderResponseDecorator());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this same problem and found that the Wicket In Action tutorial leaves out the part about setting up a custom IHeaderResponseDecorator in your main Wicket Application init. The Wicket guide has a more thorough example: 
[Apache Wicket User Guide - Put JavaScript inside page body](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/single.html#resources_8)

You need something like this in your wicket Application:

```
 @Override
public void init()
{
   setHeaderResponseDecorator(new JavaScriptToBucketResponseDecorator("myKey"));
}

 /**
 * Decorates an original IHeaderResponse and renders all javascript items
 * (JavaScriptHeaderItem), to a specific container in the page.
 */
static class JavaScriptToBucketResponseDecorator implements IHeaderResponseDecorator 
{

    private String bucketName;

    public JavaScriptToBucketResponseDecorator(String bucketName) {
        this.bucketName = bucketName;
    }

    @Override
    public IHeaderResponse decorate(IHeaderResponse response) {
        return new JavaScriptFilteredIntoFooterHeaderResponse(response, bucketName);
    }

}
```